# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined kendo grid

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

//I am getting Id if I Select filter which has data then second time when there is not data I shows blank grid that's okay. But error appears then after selection of filter which has data. like if there is no data and then after I am selecting filer which shows data at that time).

```
  command: [{
                 name: "View Details", click: function (e) {
                 debugger;
                 var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                 var dataItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());//gets the dataItem for the current row
                 console.log(dataItem.Id);

     }
 }], title: "", width: "100px"
```

My View Script:

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: dataSourceOutMessage,
                pageable:
                        {
                            height: 50,
                            pageSize: 50,
                            buttonCount: 50
                        },
                groupable: true,
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                refresh: true,
                dataBound: onDataBound,

                columns: [
                         { field: "Id", title: "ID", width: "100px", hidden: true },
                         { field: "Uname", title: "Full Name", width: "100px" },
                         { field: "Utype", title: "User Type", width: "100px" },
                             {
                                 field: "   ",
                                 title: "Method",
                                 headerAttributes: {
                                     style: "text-align: center;"
                                 },
                                 width: "120px",
                                 attributes: { "class": "table-cell", style: "text-align: center" },
                                 template: kendo.template($("#templatePopover").html())      
                             },
                             {
                                 command: [{
                                     name: "View Details", click: function (e) {
                                         //debugger;
                                         e.preventDefault();
                                         console.log(e);
                                         var list2 = '@Url.Action("GetMessagetDetials", "OutGoingMessage")';
                                         var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

                                         console.log(dataItem.Id);

                                     $.ajax({
                                         type: "GET",
                                         url: list2,
                                         dataType: 'json',
                                         data: { "Id": dataItem.Id },

                                         success: function (data) {
                                             $("#myModal").modal();
                                             $("#myModal").find(".modal-body").html(data);
                                         },
                                         error: function () {
                                             alert("There was an error attempting to delete the property.");
                                         }
                                     });

                                     $("#myModal").modal();

                                 }
                             }], title: "", width: "100px"
                         },
                       {
                           field: "CreatedOn", title: "Created Date", width: "100px",
                           template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(CreatedOn, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss tt'), 'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss') #"
                       }


            ]

        }).data("kendoGrid");
```

Comment: Please provide schema detail or full grid's code.

Answer (score 0):

To get the data item for the current row, you need this:

```
command: [{
        name: "View Details", click: function (e) {
          debugger;
          var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
          console.log(dataItem.Id);
        }
}], title: "", width: "200px"
```

What are you doing at the moment is to get the selected item, which might be null if no item is selected.